# Scala: generic function multiplying Numerics of different types

Tags: scala, generics, numeric, implicit

I am trying to write a generic weighted average function. 
I want to relax the requirements on the values and the weights being of the same type. ie, I want to support sequences of say: `(value:Float,weight:Int)` and `(value:Int,weight:Float)` arguments and not just: `(value:Int,weight:Int)`

To do so, I first need to implement a function that takes two generic numerical values and returns their product.

```
def times[A: Numeric, B: Numeric](x: B, y: A): (A, B) : ??? = {...}
```

Writing the signature and thinking about the return type, made me realise that I need to define some sort of hierarchy for Numerics to determine the return type. ie `x:Float*y:Int=z:Float`, `x:Float*y:Double=z:Double`.

Now, Numeric class defines operations `plus`, `times`, etc. only for arguments of the same type. I think I would need to implement a type:

```
class NumericConverter[Numeirc[A],Numeric[B]]{
type BiggerType=???
}
```

so that I can write my times function as:

```
def times[A: Numeric, B: Numeric](x: B, y: A): (A, B) :
NumericConverter[Numeirc[A],Numeric[B]].BiggerType= {...}
```

and convert the "smaller type" to the "bigger one" and feed it to `times()`.

Am I on the right track? How would I "implement" the `BiggerType`?

clearly I can't do something like:

```
type myType = if(...) Int else Float
```

as that is evaluated dynamically, so it worn't work.

I understand that I might be able to do this Using Scalaz, etc. but this is an academic exercise and I want to understand **how to write a function that statically returns a type based on the argument types**.

Feel free to let me know if there is a whole easier way of doing this.

**update**:

this is what I came up with it.

```
abstract class NumericsConvert[A: Numeric,B: Numeric]{

    def AisBiggerThanB: Boolean

    def timesA=new PartialFunction[(A,B), A] {
        override def isDefinedAt(x: (A, B)): Boolean = AisBiggerThanB
        override def apply(x: (A, B)): A = implicitly[Numeric[A]].times(x._1, x._2.asInstanceOf[A])
    }

    def timesB=new PartialFunction[(A,B), B] {
        override def isDefinedAt(x: (A, B)): Boolean = !AisBiggerThanB
        override def apply(x: (A, B)): B = implicitly[Numeric[B]].times(x._1.asInstanceOf[B], x._2)
    }
    def times: PartialFunction[(A, B), Any] = timesA orElse timesB
}

def times[A: Numeric, B: Numeric](x: B, y: A)= implicitly[NumericsConvert[A,B]].times(x,y)
```

which is silly as I will have to create implicits for both

```
IntDouble extends NumericsConvert[Int,Double]
```

and

```
DoubleInt extends NumericsConvert[Double,Int]
```

not to mention that the return type of `times` is now `Any`, but regardless, I am getting errors for my times functions. I thought I would add it here in case it might help with arriving at a solution. so side question: **how I can pass context bound types of one class/function to another like I am trying to do in times**.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think you're making this harder than it needs to be.

You need "evidence" that both parameters are `Numeric`. With that established let the evidence do the work. Scala will employ [numeric widening](http://scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.11/06-expressions.html#value-conversions) so that the result is the more general of the two received types.

```
def mult[T](a: T, b: T)(implicit ev:Numeric[T]): T =
  ev.times(a,b)
```

If you want to get a little fancier you can pull in the required implicits. Then it's a little easier to read and understand.

```
def mult[T: Numeric](a: T, b: T): T = {
  import Numeric.Implicits._
  a * b
}
```

Proof:

```
mult(2.3f , 7)  //res0: Float = 16.1
mult(8, 2.1)    //res1: Double = 16.8
mult(3, 2)      //res2: Int = 6
```

For more on generic types and numeric widening, [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39277033/type-parameters-and-numeric-widening), and its answer, are worth studying.

Comment: feel free to add references to http://scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.11/06-expressions.html#value-conversions in your answer to explain what happens behind the scene.

Comment: Ok, so I got my method working, but there is a slight problem with it. see if you can help me solve it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43382282/scala-generic-weighted-average-function